# get combinations of vector elements

Tags: clojure

I just wander if there any reducer in clojure that can give the same result as the below function without using recursion

the function should take a vector and returns combinations of its items (e.g. giving [1 2 3] and returns ((1 2 3) (1 2) (1 3) (1) (2 3) (2) (3) []))

```
(def combinations
"creates combinations of items for example [1 2 3]
will generate ((1 2 3) (1 2) (1 3) (1) (2 3) (2) (3) [])"
(memoize (fn[items]
(if (empty? items) [[]]
(let [els (combinations (rest items))]
    (concat  (map #(cons (first items) %)els) els))))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to use a Clojure math lib.

For leiningen `project.clj` add this- 
[[org.clojure/math.combinatorics "0.1.3"]](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics)

To use-

```
(ns example.core
  (:require [clojure.math.combinatorics :as c]))

(c/subsets [1 2 3])
;;=> (() (1) (2) (3) (1 2) (1 3) (2 3) (1 2 3))
```

You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/math/combinatorics.clj#L212) for a recursion-less solution if don't want the lib.